# ScrollView doesn't scroll when I select the auto-layout option

Tags: ios, scrollview, autolayout

Would anyone know why this might be happening?

I have a scroll view around all the elements on a screen. If I uncheck the auto-layout box, it scrolls. If I check the auto-layout box, the scrolling no longer happens.

Has anyone seen this before or knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Autolayout and scrollViews are a special case.

Wrap your scrollView in a UIView (call it contentView for example) and set the bottom constraints from the scrollView to its parent. The OS will figure out the rest.

This is a pretty good demo video about your exact problem. Autolayout examples are towards the end:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18

Also, here's a Tech Note from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html